# django channles channels.exceptions.Channels Full

Tags: python, django, websocket, django-channels

i am pretty new in django-channels and python, i make a demo using django-channels and django to send data from backend to front activly. the code in consumers.py as below:

```
websocket_clients = []

class WebsocketConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):       
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    """
    initial a new thread when new websocket instance initialed.
    """
    super(WebsocketConsumer, self).__init__(self)
    self.index_websocket = GendataThread()


    async def connect(self):
        self.index_websocket.channels_name = self.channel_name
        print('channel_name', self.channel_name)
        self.index_websocket.start()
        websocket_clients.append(self.channel_name)
        await self.accept()


    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        """disconnected a websocket instance, and stop the thread."""

        self.index_websocket.stop()
        time.sleep(2)
        index = websocket_clients.index(self.channel_name)
        websocket_clients.pop(index)


    async def receive(self, text_data):
        """receive message from connected client, wouldn't work in this project."""
        text_data = '{"message": "%s"}' % (text_data)
        text_data_json = json.loads(text_data)


    async def chat_message(self, event):
    """send message to websocket."""
        print('event', event)
        await self.send(text_data=json.dumps(
        {'message': event['message']}))


def websocket_send_data(data, channel_name):
    """
    send data to front in websocket protocol,
    :param data: data which will be sent,
    :param channel_name: a symbol to mark connected client.
    :return:
    """
    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    event = {
        "type": "chat.message",
        "message": data
    }
    async_to_sync(channel_layer.send)(channel_name, event)
```

as you can see, i make a function name: websocket_send_data(data, channel_name),which i can call in GendataThread() as below:

```
class GendataThread(threading.Thread):
    """new thread
    thread for getting data from cluster, and send to front with websocket protocol.
    """
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GendataThread, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.channels_name = None

    def run(self):
        while true:
          websocker_send_data('1', self.channels_name)
```

in this case, i can send data from backend to front while django project is running, i connect to the url

```
ws://127.0.0.1:8000/ws/intime_data
```

which is set in routing.py as below:

```
websocket_urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^ws/intime_data$', consumers.WebsocketConsumer),
]
```

i can receive data at front, but as it runs a few minutes, things were going wrong:

```
aioredis.errors.ReplyError: OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

i think is because redis is full by saving data,but i don't want these data,i try to config redis.conf by:

```
maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru
```

but still comes error when maxmemory is used. and sometimes will comes such error:

```
channels.exceptions.Channels Full
```

i think channels is using redis as a cache, but i don't know why errors come, can anyone helps me? thanks in advance.

Comment: what Layer are you using? InMemoryChannelLayer for example users a python `Queue` object so this will fill up very fast.

Comment: hey, i am using redis_layer as InMemoryChannelLayer was no longer available since channels version up to 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

you add this code to your `settings.py`:

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    "default": {
        "BACKEND": "asgi_redis.RedisChannelLayer",
        "CONFIG": {
            "hosts": [(XXX, XXX)],
        },
        "ROUTING": "XXXXXchannel_routing"
    },
 }
```